# MIMIC II WAVEFORM V2 and V3 annotation file

Tags: mimic-iii

On MIMIC II Waveform version 2 (http://www.physionet.org/pn5/mimic2db/), have 
an additional .alM annotation file for the 498 records listed in RECORDS.alM and alarm annotation files, with "chan" field that has been used to indicate if the alarm was judged to be true (1) or false (3) by expert human review. 
Is mimics II version 3 (https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/) also contains this files?

another question about the annotation file - in the website is written "The timestamp associated with each alert indicates when the definition for the corresponding alert is satisfied (not the time of onset of the condition)"
, what does it mean that the timestamp next to CHAN column indicate when corresponding alert is satisfied?

Thanks